# How to automatically run tests in Spock when building an application?

Tags: java, maven, testing, spock

I would like all tests in Spock to be enabled automatically when building the application.
The application is written in java, maven and spring. How do I configure this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example which contains a fully functional maven configuration for running Spock tests.